# Function arguments not evaluating

Tags: vim, vimdiff

I'm trying to set up a couple of maps to quickly go through merge conflicts. Here's my code:

```
func! DiffAccept(w)
  diffget a:w
  diffupdate
  normal ]c
endfunc

noremap dh :exec DiffAccept("//2")<CR>
noremap dl :exec DiffAccept("//3")<CR>
```

Every time I try to use this I get "No matching buffer for a:w". I'm clearly using this variable wrong, but it acts as expected when I change the line to "echo a:w".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vim's evaluation rules are different than most programming languages. You need to use `:execute` in order to evaluate the (function argument) variable; otherwise, it's taken literally (as a buffer name):

```
execute 'diffget' a:w
```

---

PS: Prefer using `:normal!` (with `!`); this avoids interference from mappings.

Comment: +1 btw @Ingo, `exec 'foo '.'bar'` and `exec 'foo' 'bar'`, which format do you prefer?